# Trouble parsing "raw" output of `go tool pprof`

Tags: parsing, go, file-format, pprof

I am using Golang's pprof to profile my application. I get this .pb file that I can open using

```
go tool pprof profile.pb
```

And from within the tool I enter

```
(pprof) raw
```

which "Outputs a text representation of the raw profile", according to the docs. This outputs

```
PeriodType: wall nanoseconds
Period: 10000000
Time: 2020-06-09 08:56:49.487 -0400 EDT
Duration: 20s
Samples:
sample/count wall/nanoseconds
       1950 19490080000: 1 2 3 4 5 6 
          0    3040000: 7 
          0      80000: 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 2 3 4 5 6 
          0      80000: 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 2 3 4 5 6 
          0    4000000: 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 29 30 47 2 3 4 5 6 
.
.
.
Locations
     1: 0x0 M=1 start /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py:863 s=0()
     2: 0x0 M=1 main app/web.py:485 s=0()
     3: 0x0 M=1 main /home/myapp.py:196 s=0()
     4: 0x0 M=1 <module> /home/myapp.py:227 s=0()
.
.
.
```

## What I don't understand

My understanding is that pprof is a sample-based profiler. This is reflected in the dump above because each line seems to represent an instance of a certain sample. The numbers off to the right must be indices into the table of locations.

The confusing part is the "sample/count", in the header of the first table, and the fact that so many samples seem to have a count of zero. If they have a count of zero, why would they even be there in the first place? What then does "sample/count" mean, precisely?

Comment: Compare this to the normal output of pprof which is intended for humans.

Comment: @Volker thanks. The output intended for humans is clear to me, but many of the items in the raw output shown here do not appear there